# Should multiple threads read from the same DataInputStream?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'd like my program to get a file, and then create 4 files based on its byte content.

Working with only the main thread, I just create one `DataInputStream` and do my thing sequentially.

Now, I'm interested in making my program concurrent. Maybe I can have four threads - one for each file to be created.

I don't want to read the file's bytes into memory all at once, so my threads will need to query the `DataInputStream` constantly to stream the bytes using `read()`.

What is not clear to me is, should my 4 threads call `read()` on the same `DataInputStream`, or should each one have their own separate stream to read from?

Comment: do you want read data from 4 separate file?

Comment: if you want to read data from a single file then why do you want it multi threaded? again DataInputStream is not thread safe.

Comment: Maybe not. The input file isn't multithreaded. The disk isn't multithreaded. Concurrency is pointless here.

Comment: @EJP: Ah, so using four threads won't make a difference if all they do is create files?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a good idea. See http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html

> DataInputStream is not necessarily safe for multithreaded access. Thread safety is optional and is the responsibility of users of methods in this class.

Comment: Besides, I would use 4 processes, or even http://netty.io/ if you don't need that your 4 threads know each other workings...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want all of the data in each of your four new files, each thread should create its own DataInputStream.

If the threads share a single DataInputStream, at best each thread will get some random quarter of the data.  At worst, you'll get a crash or data corruption due to multithreaded access to code that is not thread safe.

Comment: yes, Here most costly operation is file reading. so if a single thread do the reading operation , the same thread can easily do new file creation task. again, in this scenario you can not deploy multithread.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read data from 1 file into 4 separate ones you will not share DataInputStream.  You can however wrap that stream and add functionality that would make it thread safe.

For example you may want to read in a chunk of data from your DataInputStream and cache that small chunk.  When all 4 threads have read the chunk you can dispose of it and continue reading.  You would never have to load the complete file into memory.  You would only have to load a small amount.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the doc of DataInputStream. It is a FilterInputStream, which means the read operation is delegated to other inputStream. Suppose you use here is a FileInputStream, In most platform, concurrent read will be supported.

So in your case, you should initialize four different FileInputStream, result in four DataInputStream, used in four thread separately. The read operation will not be interfered.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

Longer answer: have a single thread read the DataInputStream, and put the data into one of four Queues, one per output file.  Decide which Queue based upon the byte content.

Have four threads, each one reading from a Queue, that write to the output files.